# How can I pass messages between objects in Java

Tags: java, oop, class-method, object-relationships

I am attempting to pass messages between objects in Java with OOP concept. I created two classes named Doctor and Receptionist, and I want instances of the Receptionist class to send messages to Doctor's objects. I also want objects of class Patient to send a message (books an appointment) to objects of class Appointments.

In summary, I want to achieve a relationship and communication between different instances of different classes.

**Patient Class**

```
public class Patient 
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String condition;

    public Patient (int id, String name, int age, String condition)
    {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setName("name");
        this.setAge(age);
        this.setCondition("condition");
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getAge()
    {
        return this.age;
    }
    public void setCondition(String condition)
    {
        this.condition = condition;
    }
    public String getCondition()
    {
        return this.condition;
    }
}
```

**Appointment class**

```
public class Appointment {
    private int appointId;
    private String date;
    private String purpose;
    
    public Appointment (int appointId, String date, String purpose)
    {
        this.setAppointId(appointId);
        this.setDate("date");
        this.setPurpose("purpose");
    }
    public void setAppointId(int appointId)
    {
        this.appointId = appointId;
    }
    public void setDate(String date)
    {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public void setPurpose(String purpose)
    {
        this.purpose = purpose;
    }
}
```

How can I have a method that books an appointment in the class Patient; and when the method is called, it creates an instance of Appointment?

Comment: you can create a method with `Appointment` as return type. inside the method you create a `new` `Appointment ` and return it. Just rememeber that if you create this method in `Patient` you will have to ìnclude` Àppointment` in it  in order to be recognized

Comment: Actually, this is where dependency injection comes into play. But if you just wanna see then I am providing an example below.

Comment: “passing messages” in Java = calling methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is message passing in OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765555/what-is-message-passing-in-oop)

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and the help. @AmimulEhsanRahi, I really appreciate your answer below. It was helpful. Please, how can I have a mechanism that detects when an instance of Appointment is created and also stores it in an array.

Comment: @CelestineAkpanoko you can know appointment was created when you invoke the bookAnAppointment() method.........the method will return an appointment object.......so, you can store the return value of bookAnAppointment() in an array.........

Answer (score 0):

Your Patient class may look like this:

```
public class Patient {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String condition;

    public Patient( int id, String name, int age, String condition ) {
        this.setId(id);
        this.setName("name");
        this.setAge(age);
        this.setCondition("condition");
    }

    public void setId( int id ) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setName( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setAge( int age ) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public void setCondition( String condition ) {
        this.condition = condition;
    }

    public String getCondition() {
        return this.condition;
    }

    public Appointment bookAnAppointment( int appointId, String date, String purpose ) {
        return new Appointment(appointId, date, purpose);
    }
}
```